# Laravel Slugable Route Model Binding weird behaviour

Tags: laravel, route-model-binding

I have a section in my project with the latest news articles. For this I have a:

1. Post model
2. Post resource controller and a
3. Resource Post Route.

**Post Model**

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Sluggable;

    protected $fillable = [...,...];

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }

    public function sluggable(): array
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'title'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

**PostController.php**

```php
public function show(Post $post)
{
    dd($post);
}
```

**web.php**

```php
Route::resource('/posts', App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class)->only(['index','show']);
```

Index (`http://localhost/news`) and show (`http://localhost/news/{slug}`) work as expected!

### Now the problem/bug I noticed:

When I change the route from **posts** to **news**, the show method no longer works.
Index still works.

**the modified route from posts to news**

```php
Route::resource('/news', App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class)->only(['index','show']);
```

`http://localhost/news` works but `http://localhost/news/{slug}` shows me only the PostModel Structure.

Do you know the problem and what do I have to do to make it work? I use Laravel 8 and `"cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^8.0" package`for the slugs. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've figured it out. I'm writing the answer here for anyone who might have the same problem as me. First of all. It is not a bug. If you adjust the route so that the model name is no longer included in the route, then you have to bind the route explicitly. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#explicit-binding

All you have to do. In the boot() method of **RouteServiceProvider.php**, add the desired route and bind it with the desired classes. In my case it was news instead of post.

```
public function boot()
{
    ....
    Route::model('news', \App\Models\Post::class);
}
```